# Unit testing a Configuration in spring Batch which runs in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am Using Spring boot application to run  spring batch and I have a Config java class which loads all configuration related stuff like getting some values from properties file and setting them, calling reader,writers etc.

I am trying to run a junit for just few methods in that config class from my unit test class. how can we achieve that. I am trying to use SpringRunner Can someone through some light .

Comment: So you basically want to test your `@Configuration` class? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909482/3635454

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: didnt get much help with thay

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74) ~[spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]

Comment: `I am trying to run a junit for just few methods in that config class` Are you trying to test the configuration code? Or do you want to test the spring batch job itself or one of its components (reader, writer, etc) ? Please share the code you want to test with an example of the expected result to be able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you please update your question with more details? I would recommend to go to official documentation https://spring.io/docs