# Junit5 - SpringBoot: Error creating bean with name after applied configuration in WebSecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

Link to the project on Github: https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/tree/develop

I have these tests for a controller:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class PingControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private PingService pingService;
    
    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;

    @Test
    void indexShouldReturnApiVersion() throws Exception {
        
        when(pingService.show()).thenReturn(appVersion);
        
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version", is(appVersion)));
    }

}
```

It works, and it works very well.

I added a new class:

```java
package com.bitbank.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.bitbank.services.v1.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import com.bitbank.utils.JwtUtils;
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, null);
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I edited `WebSecurityConfig` as follow, adding `http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    private List<String> getAllowedOrigins() {
        return Arrays.asList("http://localhost:[*]", "https://online-banking-frontend.netlify.app",
                "https://online-banking-frontend.vercel.app");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/api/v1/ping").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/bank-account-transactions").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // THIS IS THE ISSUE! =========>
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(getAllowedOrigins());
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

After this, I got error on tests (but not on real launch of Spring)

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationJwtTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bitbank.utils.JwtUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationJwtTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bitbank.utils.JwtUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

No qualifying bean of type 'com.bitbank.utils.JwtUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

#### Edit n. 1

I added some MockedBean:

```java
class PingControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    // new
    @MockBean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter;
    
    // new
    @MockBean
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
    @MockBean
    private PingService pingService;
    
    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;
```

And now I have a different issue:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute name must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.setAttribute(MockHttpServletRequest.java:762)
```

#### Edit n 2

At the end, I got green tests:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class PingControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    @Autowired
    AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;
    
    @MockBean
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
    @MockBean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    
    @MockBean
    private PingService pingService;
    
    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;
    
    @Test
    void indexShouldReturnApiVersion() throws Exception {
        
        when(pingService.show()).thenReturn(appVersion);
        
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version", is(appVersion)));
    }
}
```

And now all test are green.

Comment: I think you need something like a @TestConfiguration for you tests since the normal application configuration is not used in tests. Check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909345/how-to-test-spring-configuration-classes

Comment: I don't have a single configuration (see at my project), so I don't know what introduce...

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I was missing some Autowired and Bean.

final code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class PingControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;

@MockBean
JwtUtils jwtUtils;

@MockBean
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

@MockBean
private PingService pingService;

@Value("${app.version}")
private String appVersion;

@Test
void indexShouldReturnApiVersion() throws Exception {

    when(pingService.show()).thenReturn(appVersion);

    mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version", is(appVersion)));
}
}
```